# Complementary error function in matlab

Tags: limits, special-functions, matlab

Please I really want to know how to verify the following relation in MatLAB

$\text{erfc}(x)\overset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{x\sqrt{\pi}}$

Comment: It would be more accurate to use $\sim_{x \to \infty}$ instead of $\overset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}$ since $\to$ usually denotes a limit being taken (in this context).  Also, could you be more specific about what kind of verification you're looking for?  It's simple to verify this by hand using L'Hopital's rule, for instance.

Comment: Isn't the expression about limit? What do you mean by $\sim_{x \to \infty}$ anyway?

Comment: By definition $f(x) \sim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ means $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1.$$  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) for some more info.  This is the standard way to write the type of relationship you're interested in (the one between $\operatorname{erfc}(x)$ and $e^{-x^2}/x\sqrt{\pi}$).

Comment: I checked the link but doesn't help me, I just want to prove the relation in Matlab, anyway it is verified is okay for me.

Comment: I'm not sure Matlab can prove this type of statement.  I would be interested to see if it could.  As I said, it is straightforward to verify it by hand using L'Hopital's rule instead.

Comment: Yea, I know it can be verified using L'Hopital's rule Antonio. Thanks for your info.

Comment: If you want to *prove* this with Matlab, you will need a symbolic computation toolbox (I think it's MuPAD since Mathworks bought it a few years ago). Otherwise, you can show the relation numerically, but it's not a proof.

Comment: Do you mean Matlab symbolic facility? If it's what you mean, as far as I can tell, it is available right from R2009 version up to date.

Comment: I mean this: http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/symbolic/

Comment: How about the numerical? How should I go about it?

Comment: Numerically what you could do is plug a really large number into $\operatorname{erfc}(x)/\left(e^{-x^2}/(x\sqrt{\pi})\right)$ or plot it for very large $x$.  It should be very close to $1$.

Comment: Okay, I will try. @AntonioVargas. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is *not* the limit of the complementary error function for $x \rightarrow \infty$ (that's zero). It is also not the [asymptotic series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) of the function. Rather, it is just the first term in the the [asymptotic series expansion](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfc/06/02/), but it's a very good approximation.

To find the limit using Matlab, you can use the [`limit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/limit.html) function in the Symbolic Math toolbox:

```
syms x;
limit(erfc(x),x,Inf)
```

To find the asymptotic series expansion you're going to have to use [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html). However, it is possible to [call MuPAD functions from Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136111/2278029). Using the [`series`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/series.html) function here is how you can obtain the first terms in the series from Matlab:

```
syms x;
s = feval(symengine,'series',erfc(x),x==Inf,5)
t1 = feval(symengine,'nthmonomial',s,1)
t2 = feval(symengine,'nthmonomial',s,2)
t3 = feval(symengine,'nthmonomial',s,3)
```

which returns

```
t1 =

exp(-x^2)/(pi^(1/2)*x)


t2 =

-exp(-x^2)/(2*pi^(1/2)*x^3)


t3 =

(3*exp(-x^2))/(4*pi^(1/2)*x^5)
```

In other words, for $x \in \mathbb{R}, x\rightarrow \infty$ and using [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

$$\text{erfc}(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x \sqrt\pi} (1 + O(x^{-2}))$$

None of this is a "proof" of anything, but you'll be happy to know that the above results match up with what Mathematica returns.

Comment: Okay, so must I use the MuPAD, @horchler?

Comment: @YYG: No one here really fully understands what you're trying to do or what you mean by "verify". I showed you how you can call MuPAD from Matlab to obtain the series expansion. This shows you exactly how good your approximation is. You can also learn MuPAD and use that by itself. Since the asymptotic series expansion for this function is well known and published in many books, you can likely cite one of those or Matlab. I suggest that you play around with my code and the other ideas here.

Comment: Okay horchler. By the way, by verify, I meant just to check how the relation holds, I didn't mean to proof. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. From the recent paper by Karbach et al.:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0748v1.pdf

substitute Eq(37) in Eq(13), replace $-iz$ to $z$, take the limit $z \to \infty$ and you will get the answer.